# Can I run some SQL in a separate transaction, during a transaction

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, transactional, error-logging

I'm trying to create some standard logging for stored procedures along with our standard error handling. I want to call a stored procedure at the beginning of the sproc to log to a table that it has started, and call a stored procedure at the end to log that it has successfully completed. I also want to call a stored procedure from the error handler to log the failure and errors message/number.

The stored procedure may have its own transaction, or its calling stack may have started a transaction, or there may be no transaction open. I don't want any of my calls to the logging procedures to be rolled back at all, no matter what happens in the main transaction. i.e. the processing of the logging stored procedures needs to be completely separate from that of the main processing.

Is it possible to execute some SQL as though it is in a separate session during a transaction? What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Incidentally, I can't use xp_cmdshell, otherwise I'd shell a call to sqlcmd.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: I suggest you read Erland's discussion of error handling [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). It discusses error handling in general. Note also that linked servers are notoriously fragile.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is nested transactions. However, nested transactions are not real. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/ You would have to do your logging in another context. Since you are in a stored procedure you would have to use dynamic sql in your logging code for this to work.

Comment: No, I'm not describing nested transactions. I understand savepoints and how to use them. I want to execute some SQL completely unconnected to the existing transactions. I need to call a sproc that will commit in its own right, straight away, completely disconnected to whether the calling code is in a transaction or not.

Comment: You stated in your post that the "calling stack may have started a transaction". That indicates that procA started a transaction, then you call your logging procedure and then returns to procA. That by definition is a nested transaction.

Comment: not, ProcA starts the transaction, then calls ProcB which is not transaction aware. Both sprocs should call the logging sprocs (which should commit irrespective of transactions). There may be a ProcC, ProcD and so on. I was meaning that the transaction processing was held somewhere up the calling stack; I could have been clearer. I'm not a fan of nesting transactions.

Comment: But they can't commit independent of transactions in the calling procedure. That is what I am telling you. That is nested transactions.

Comment: I think I've found what I'm look here here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236610/can-i-exclude-a-stored-procedure-from-a-transaction-in-ms-sql?rq=1). If I perform a call back into the server using a linked server (wrapped in a sproc) it gives me the process I'm looking for. Effectively executing a piece of SQL on a separate session.

Comment: Yeah that would do it.